# Открытие элемента в том же блоке где нажата кнопка

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$('.button').click(function() {
    $('.down_i').slideToggle();
})
```

C помощью кнопки с классом `button` применяю функцию `slideToggle` на нужный мне блок с классом `down_i`.
Когда блоков `.down_i` становится два и больше, при клике на `.button` любого из блоков открываются сразу все существующие `.down_i`.
Как сделать так, чтобы открывался только `.down_i` того блока, на кнопку которого я кликаю?

HTML:

```
<div class="items_1-c">
    <div class="item">
        <div class="up_i">
            <div class="button">פרטים נוספים</div>
        </div>
        <div class="down_i">
            <h4 class="h4">:פרטים נוספים</h4>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="item">
        <div class="up_i">
            <div class="button">פרטים נוספים</div>
        </div>
        <div class="down_i">
            <h4 class="h4">:פרטים נוספים</h4>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <div class="item">
        <div class="up_i">
            <div class="button">פרטים נוספים</div>
        </div>
        <div class="down_i">
            <h4 class="h4">:פרטים נוספים</h4>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: что значит *down_i того блока на кнопку которого я кликаю* - как ты определяешь что down_i  принадлежит какому-то блоку?

Comment: Потому что он завернут в блок как и button зачем вообще здесь что-то определять??

Comment: @soledar10, так не сработает :-) посмотри его разметку. А у тебя в примере почему-то `.btn` вместо `.button`

Comment: Для лучшего понимания стоило добавить **минимальный** пример, воспроизводящий проблему. А тут присутствует куча не относящейся напрямую к вопросу разметки. Ну и `$(this).closest('.item').find(".down_i").slideToggle()`.

Comment: @Regent, ну или `$(this).parent().next().slideToggle()`

Comment: @LiEm, что ты понимаешь под _блоком_? кнопка с классом `button` у тебя внутри `up_i` - что никак не связано с `down_i`

Comment: @Grundy но этот подход куда более хрупкий, так что я стараюсь с ним не связываться)

Comment: @LiEm перенесу в ответ, чтобы вопрос можно было считать решенным.

Answer (score 3):

От кнопки переходим к блоку `.item`, в котором она находится, после чего в этом блоке ищем блок `.down_i`:

```js
$('.button').on("click", function() {
  $(this).closest(".item").find(".down_i").slideToggle()
});
```

```html
<div class="item">
  <div class="up_i">
    <div class="button">Button1</div>
  </div>
  <div class="down_i">Text1</div>
</div>
<div class="item">
  <div class="up_i">
    <div class="button">Button2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="down_i">Text2</div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```